# Generating Random Numbers and Letters

Tags: vbscript

Keep getting this error sometimes when mid is ZERO:

> Invalid procedure call or argument: 'Mid'

How would I fix this?

```
Function CreateRandomString(iSize)
    Const VALID_TEXT = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
    Dim sNewSearchTag
    Dim I

    For I = 0 To iSize
        Randomize
        sNewSearchTag = sNewSearchTag & Mid(VALID_TEXT,Round(Rnd * Len(VALID_TEXT)),1)
    Next

    CreateRandomString = sNewSearchTag
End Function
```

Comment: Couple of things you only need to call `Randomize()` once and what happens if `Rnd()` returns zero or a negative value? Might explain why `Mid()` complains, you can't select a zero length of a string, can you?? You need to specify a random range `(Rnd() * UpperRange) + LowerRange)` will work.

Comment: Better explanation of a random range function here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36842301/692942

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vbscript execute a function rarely, with chances using random](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36840136/vbscript-execute-a-function-rarely-with-chances-using-random)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why vbscript Mid function shows error 'Invalid Procedure Call or argument : Mid'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13970723/692942).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the random range to be correct you need to make sure the random value generated is between 1 and the length of the `VALID_TEXT` string value.

The simple formula to do this using `Rnd()` is

```
(Rnd() * Len(VALID_TEXT)) + 1
```

also move `Randomize()` outside the loop, as it is you'll just make it less random as you're resetting the seed with every iteration of the loop.

The reason for the error is [`Mid()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3(v=vs.84).aspx) expects a valid start and size, which a zero value is not. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13970723/692942) for more information.

More information about random number ranges can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36842301/692942) to another question.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument of [Mid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3(v=vs.84).aspx) is 1 based. That means that if you did:

```
Mid(VALID_TEXT,1,1)
```

you will get "a", not "b" as you might be expecting.

An easy fix would be to add 1 to the second argument, but then you'll run into the same problem on the top end. Typically people will round a random number down after multiplying it instead of using Math.Round, either view Math.Floor or Integer truncation.

Comment: Wrong link this is VBScript not Visual Basic. Also VBScript doesn't have `Math.Round()` or `Math.Floor()`.